# ssconvert - How to specify a specific field format

Tags: logstash, gnumeric, ssconvert

I'm looking for the way to specify a field format when converting an `.xlsx` file to csv using **ssconvert** tool on linux.

I want this information because actually, I have a field that is in `floating point` type but after conversion, it comes as a string.

For exemple: `99,8923` become `"99,8923"` but other values in the same field are correctly parsed, like `54` is `54` and that's normal.

The probleme is with `"` added around the number. While parsing this number with **Logstash**, it becomes `998923` even if I specify in logstash that it is a `float`.

Thanks for your help.